# W3 total cache not minifying certain js file

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

Do you have any idea why W3 Total Cache is not minifying this one javascript file? https://www.gadrilling.com/wp-content/cache/minify/64ba3.js

The rest of JS files are completely fine and minified, so it shouldnt be the plugin settings.

This specific file is quite large, maybe some max file size limitation from the plugin?

Comment: check the file permission of that file.

Answer (score 0):

I probably think that you have chosen option to have a single JavaScript file combining all the JavaScript that loads in a page.

If so then, you can't do anything.

If not then you should probably figured it out by unchecking options of the Cache plugin one by one.